# Sencha: Cannot call method 'getHeader' of undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am try to update the record of a **dataview.List** from with the data modified from it's associate **form.Panel**

code:

```
onListItemTap:function(list,index,target,record,e){
            this.getMain().push({
            xtype:'userform',
            title:record.data.name,
            record:record,
            listeners:{
                        hide:function(form){
                            record.setData(form.getValues());
                            list.refresh();
                        }
                    }
            });
        },
```

Code after **record.setData(...);list.refresh();**
page getting error:
 
***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getHeader' of undefined***

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there are issue with the sencha touch 2.3.1 that I am using. 
I simply comment the **grouped=true** property in **List** component. It works.

code:

```
       {
        xtype:'list',
        id:'list-user',
        store:'Users',
        itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(...),
        flex:1,
        //grouped:true
        }
```

hope this finding will save time and from frustration for you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the method updateHeaderMap List component.

```
Ext.define('Nerine.override.List', {
    override:'Ext.dataview.List',

    updateHeaderMap: function() {

        var me = this,
            headerMap = me.headerMap,
            headerIndices = me.headerIndices,
            header, i, item;

        headerMap.length = 0;
        for (i in headerIndices) {
            if (headerIndices.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                /* fix bug  */
//                console.log('aaa', me.getItemAt(i)); return null
//                console.log('bbb', me.getItemAt(i).getHeader());
                if( !(item = me.getItemAt(i))) {
                    continue;
                }
                header = me.getItemAt(i).getHeader();
                headerMap.push(header.renderElement.dom.offsetTop);
            }

        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The group headers have no records in the store. This override solves the issue by checking whether the record for which scrollToRecord is called really is in the store. Furthermore it solves the issue that when calling scrollToRecord is done in `painted` event, it is possible that the headerMap is not yet ready, which means that the pinnedHeader is not correctly updated when using scrollToRecord.

```
Ext.define("MyApp.override.List", {
    override:'Ext.dataview.List',
    scrollToRecord: function(record, animate, overscroll) {
        var me = this,
            store = me.getStore(),
            index = store.indexOf(record);
        if(index>-1 && index < this.listItems.length) {
            this.updateHeaderMap();
            this.callOverridden(arguments);
        }
    }
});
```